# In java character replace using charAt

Tags: java

I am trying to take input two strings and i am checking if any character of 1st string is equal to 2nd string character then replace it with '*'
My code is

```
for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
        {
            if(s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j))
            {
                char c=s2.charAt(j);
                c='*';
                System.out.println(s2);
            }
        }
    }
```

but it is not getting replaced what should i do to make the code run properly ?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java, you can’t replace a character, you need to create a new String instead

Comment: Please [search](/search?q=replace+char+in+string+%5Bjava%5D) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: And even if strings weren't immutable (as in C), this is _copying_ the value of `charAt(j)` into a local variable and then updating the local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is immutable in Java. So, to change one single character in the middle of the `String` you have to split it and then join:

```
String str = "abcde";
String newStr = str.substring(0, 2) + "_" + str.substring(3); // "ab_de"
```

In general, you cannot change string. All modifications create **new** (modified) string. Especially, it is bad practice to modify string within loop; every iteration you get a new string instance.

To solve your problem, I offer collect all unique characters from second string into a `Set` and then use `StringBuilder` to build a result string:

```
public static String modify(String one, String two) {
    Set<Character> uniqueChars = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < two.length(); i++)
        uniqueChars.add(two.charAt(i));

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(one.length());

    for(int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++)
        buf.append(uniqueChars.contains(one.charAt(i)) ? '*' : one.charAt(i));

    return buf.toString();
}
```